# In Sonar, how to prevent checking some rules in some packages?

Tags: java, sonarqube

We have an Android/Blackberry project with a common part. That part, obviously, is written to compile to both Android and Blackberry targets, and, consequently, cannot use some of the newer Java features (e.g., Integer.valueOf). I'd like to skip some of the rules specifically for that part. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code for a better solution using `@SuppressWarnings`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you separate the common part to an own project you can add a new [Quality Profile](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+profiles) in Sonar (where you deactivated these rules) and assign it to your common project.

Apart from that you can use the

```
// NOSONAR
```

comment to supress a warning on a single line (see [FAQ](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/)).

Comment: Sonar 2.5 introduced a "SuppressWarning" annotation which also useful for switching off analysis http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1760

Comment: Unfortunately, annotations are among those newer features that are not supported on Blackberry.

Comment: As to the NOSONAR comment, there are too many violations to comment them all.

Comment: So follow the original advice and create a new more permissive quality profile in Sonar. You can make this the default for all projects.

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on your last link

Answer (score 15):

This is an older question and I think meanwhile there is a better solution:

Adding // NOSONAR to the relevant classes solves the issue somehow. But I think this is problematic since no rules will be applied in this case at all. There is another way to solve this though:
[Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues)

**Example:**

I want to ignore all issues against coding rule MagicNumbers in the package com.foobar.domain in all my java files.

In Sonar navigate to your project, go to *Configuration\Settings\Issues* and in *Ignore Issues on Multiple Criteria* add:

- Rule Key Pattern: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.MagicNumberCheck
- File Path Pattern: com/foobar/domain/*.java

[image: Sonar ignore issues]

This is all also explained very nicely in the linked documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this by adding something similar in the SonarSettings.xml from the project?