# Turning Sonar off for certain code

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, findbugs

Is it possible to turn off sonar ([www.sonarsource.org](http://www.sonarsource.org)) measurements for specific blocks of code, which one doesn't want to be measured?

An example is the "Preserve Stack Trace" warning which Findbugs outputs.  When leaving the server, I might well want to only pass the message back to the client, not including the actual exception which I just caught, if that exception is unknown to the client (because the client doesn't have the JAR in which that exception was contained for example).

Answer (score 125, accepted):

This is a [FAQ](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/). You can put `//NOSONAR` at the end of the line triggering the warning.

> **`//NOSONAR`**
>
> For most languages, SonarQube supports the use of the generic mechanism: `//NOSONAR` at the end of the line of the issue. This will suppress all issues - now and in the future - that might be raised on the line.

I prefer using the FindBugs mechanism though, which consists in adding the @SuppressFBWarnings annotation:

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings(
    value = "NAME_OF_THE_FINDBUGS_RULE_TO_IGNORE",
    justification = "Why you choose to ignore it")
```

Comment: Agreed. However, I'm not sure if Sonar correctly interprets `@SuppressFBWarnings` (added to avoid clashes with `java.lang.SuppressWarnings`) and also ignores it.

Comment: AFAIK, Sonar uses FindBugs. So if FindBugs handles these annotations, I don't see why they wouldn't work when running FindBugs through Sonar. Shouldn't be hard to test anyway.

Comment: The FAQ link is outdated. Here is the new [FAQ](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/HOME/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-Howtoremovefalsepositiveissues?)

Comment: Could you please provide other link to a SonarQube FAQ? I see a login form instead of FAQ

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/#header-1

Comment: A space is needed "//  NOSONAR" before NOSONAR.

Comment: Even that updated FAQ link is now obsolete. Looks like SonarQube itself could benefit from a rule for that issue.

Answer (score 351):

You can annotate a class or a method with SuppressWarnings

```
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:S00112")
```

**squid:S00112** in this case is a Sonar issue ID. You can find this ID in the Sonar UI. Go to Issues Drilldown. Find an issue you want to suppress warnings on. In the red issue box in your code is there a Rule link with a definition of a given issue. Once you click that you will see the ID at the top of the page.

Comment: I can confirm that this also works with a specific FindBugs rule-ID, e.g. `@SuppressWarnings("findbugs:UI_INHERITANCE_UNSAFE_GETRESOURCE")`.

Comment: The problem is that Eclipse displays a warning `Unsupported @SuppressWarnings("squid:S00112")`. You can configure Eclipse to ignore this but then a typo such as in `@SuppressWarnings("uncheckedd")` will not be detected.

Comment: See https://docs.codescan.io/hc/en-us/articles/360012109711-Ignoring-violations for docs on @SuppressWarnings and Sonar.

Comment: How do we add comments/justification when we suppress?

Comment: Looks like this answer should be marked as accepted.

Comment: Fun fact: This annotation can also be added to a class variable or even a local variable.

Answer (score 141):

I recommend you try to suppress specific warnings by using `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2078")`.

For suppressing multiple warnings you can do it like this `@SuppressWarnings({"squid:S2078", "squid:S2076"})`

There is also the `//NOSONAR` comment that tells SonarQube to ignore all errors for a specific line.

Finally if you have the proper rights for the user interface you can issue a flag as a false positive directly from the interface.

The reason why I recommend suppression of specific warnings is that it's a better practice to block a specific issue instead of using `//NOSONAR` and risk a Sonar issue creeping in your code by accident.

You can read more about this in the [FAQ](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/faq/#header-1)

Edit: 6/30/16
SonarQube is now called SonarLint

In case you are wondering how to find the squid number. Just click on the Sonar message (ex. `Remove this method to simply inherit it.`) and the Sonar issue will expand.

On the bottom left it will have the squid number (ex. `squid:S1185` Maintainability > Understandability)

So then you can suppress it by `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S1185")`

Comment: Thanks for the hint to ingnoe multiple sonar cube warnings

Comment: The other issue with marking it as a false positive on the interface is that if for whatever reason the project is deleted and added again, all of the flags you have set will be gone.

Comment: @annedroiid  - Is there any way if same can be done in pom.xml file ? I've raise question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789832/disable-sonar-rule-using-pom-xml

Answer (score 16):

Use //NOSONAR  on the line you get warning if it is something you cannot help your code with. It works!

Comment: Today, I get a warning if I use `//NOSONAR`. Super annoying.

Answer (score 6):

I not be able to find squid number in sonar 5.6, with this annotation also works:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"pmd:AvoidCatchingGenericException", "checkstyle:com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.coding.IllegalCatchCheck"})
```

Comment: `squid` is for the Sonar-sourced Java database (SonarAnalyzer Java). `pmd` and `checkstyle` are on other rule repositories.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it's a tricky to understand which is the ID of issue so i used @SuppressWarnings("all") annotation which basically  is applied of all rules but to be more precise is better to use the ID. Click to see picture ->
[Sonar Issue ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv9Hc.jpg)

So when click on "Why is this an issue?" in the red box, i you will get to a screen with explanation. On top of the screen in left side you can see rule name, and on the left the id of this rule.
So to applied for this rule only you have to add this annotation to your class or method.

@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")

Answer (score 3):

code complexity of any method is allowed only 15, if we have to resolve this issue without refactoring the methods we can use this at the top of method definition:-@SuppressWarnings({"java:S3776"})