# Exclude sonar rules

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-duplication

Is there a way to exclude sonar (version 4.0) rules with **Java** code?

Im using on my classes:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("all")
```

But sonar don't remove all issues, we still have:

- Correctness - Class defines field that masks a superclass field
- Code duplication issues

I missing something?

EDIT: [On sonar docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-SuppressWarnings) SuppressWarnings deactivates all rules, but don't work for me. This annotation only remove some rules.

Comment: which version of sonar are you using?
you might have to use the following plugin:
[Switch off violation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Switch+Off+Violations+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to refer to this [FAQ](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-NOSONAR) to get some ideas. Also, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code), you can use following code:

```
@edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressWarnings(
    value = "NAME_OF_THE_FINDBUGS_RULE_TO_IGNORE",
    justification = "Why you choose to ignore it")
```

Comment: Why not with java.lang.@SuppressWarnings("all") ?

Comment: Well, because it is ignored by Find Bugs(which sonar relies to).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ArnaudPotier and @AlexanderGavrilov

Answering my own post:

Is there a way to exclude sonar (version 4.0) rules with Java code?

Yes, but needs sonar configuration: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues

- Regular expression on files added: `javax\.annotation\.Generated`
- Annotation on class: `@Generated(value = { "someValue" })`

`java.lang.@SuppressWarnings("all")` doesn't work for all issues.