# SonarQube JavaScript disable a part of code

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

I would like to disable a block of code(say a function) in a file for analysis by SonarQube... Any suggestions on how to do that..

I found something for java here --> [Turning Sonar off for certain code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SonarQube provides plenty of options for ignoring issues in specific files and/or code blocks, see [Narrowing the Focus documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) (and to your specific case: look for *Ignore Issues in Blocks*).

Comment: An updated link: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/

Comment: But it has nothing about disabling coverage on the part of JavaScript code (block).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know Sonar respects `// NOSONAR` tag for Java projects but it looks like that is also has been implemented for JS: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-294

Comment: Apologies for such delay. `// NOSONAR` works for a single line, is there something for a block of code? like a function, or if-else-if block.

Answer (score 2):

To ignore blocks:

```
 // BEGIN-NOSCAN
const YourFunction () => {
  // Your code
}
 // END-NOSCAN
```

To ignore single lines:

```
const YourCode = 'Example'; // NOSONAR
```

You can read more about it here in the [SonarQube docs Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/). Thanks to Nicolas's answer above.

Comment: As far as I've understood, //NOSONAR is actually required to be placed at the end of the line, not on top