# Handling try-with-resources issue in Sonarqube if resource shouldn't be closed immediately

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a method that initializes a `Session` object (Cassandra Session, which according to best practices should be shared across application threads as it is quite expensive to initialize one) and returns it back to the caller. Sonarqube suggests closing my `Session` object in `finally` block or by using `try-with-resources` construct.

It doesn't make sense to do it my case as a session should be closed only when the application is shutting down.

Such check makes sense only if my resource should be closed immediately after usage, like connection, file, etc.

How do I get rid of that type of error, please advise.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109228/how-can-we-ignore-some-sonarqube-rules-in-java ? Alternatively, couldn't you just turn into the SQ user interface and ignore that warning there for that one file?

Comment: Yes, I guess I can always ignore a rule, I was thinking maybe there is a better way to handle such case.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2095")
```

This is how I ended up handling that error.