# Can Ternary operators should not be nested (squid:S3358) be configured

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

When I have the following code with 2 levels of Ternary operations

```
 double amount = isValid ? (isTypeA ? vo.getTypeA() : vo.getTypeB()) : 0;
```

Which Sonar warns about

```
Ternary operators should not be nested (squid:S3358)
```

> Just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you should, and that's the case with nested ternary operations. Nesting ternary operators results in the kind of code that may seem clear as day when you write it, but six months later will leave maintainers (or worse - future you) scratching their heads and cursing.
>
> Instead, err on the side of clarity, and use another line to express the nested operation as a separate statement.

My colleague suggested that such level can be accepted and it's more clear than the alternative.

I wonder if this rule (or others) can be configured to allowed levels limit?

If not, why sonar is so strict when it deals with code conventions?

I don't want to [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109228/how-can-we-ignore-some-sonarqube-rules-in-java) rule, just to customize to allow up to 2 levels instead of 1.

Comment: I am with Sonar on this. This should be changed to nested-if.

Comment: @Kartik I'm too, but there are opinions that reject it, can sonar be more flexible with this rule?

Comment: @Kartik I don't want to ignore, I want to customize, allow up to 2 levels instead of 1

Comment: oh sorry then, no idea.. retracting the duplicate flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if this rule can be configured to allowed levels limit?

The [Ternary operators should not be nested](https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules?open=squid%3AS3358&rule_key=squid%3AS3358) rule cannot be configured. You are only able to enable or disable it.

> I wonder if other rules can be configured to allowed levels limit?

I don't know any existing rule which can do it. Luckily, you are able to create a custom analyzer. The original rule class is here [NestedTernaryOperatorsCheck](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/d3eb9295131104fcda5871f919fd905534b15417/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/NestedTernaryOperatorsCheck.java). You can simply copy it and adjust to your needs.

> why sonar is so strict when it deals with code conventions?

SonarSource provides a lot of rules for different languages. Every customization makes code more difficult to maintain. They have a limited capacity, so they have to make decisions which are unaccepted by all users (but are accepted by most of them).

Comment: how to disable this rule ? in sonarqube or sonarlint

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/quality-profiles/