# Contradictory rules in Sonar

Tags: java, generics, sonarqube

I have a situation like the following:

```
public Map<A, List<B>> methodA() { ... }
```

with `B` being:

```
public abstract class B<T> { ... }
```

This makes Sonar to complain, telling me to `Provide the parametrized type for this generic.` But if I change it to `List<B<?>>` Sonar complains too, telling me to `Remove usage of generic wildcard type.`

I have no clue on how to fix this.

Comment: You don't know what `T` might be in the list the map contains?

Comment: "how to fix this" - ignore it?! (or have it *ignored* by Sonar itself, maybe as explained in [How can we ignore some SonarQube rules in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109612/85421))

Comment: @daniu not a concrete class. There are several which could be, that's the reason it is generic ;)

Comment: @user85421 I don't control Sonar rules in my project. It's a company thing...

Comment: then you must use a specific type, as already suggested. And using a wildcard is basically the same as having no type and, consequently, similar to having no generics (at least regarding the posted method return value.) Maybe using a new type like in `public <C> Map<A, List<B<C>>> methodA()`

Comment: This is not enough information to give a proper answer. If the `T` can be one of several classes, how is that set determined? Is it always a single one? Is this known to the caller? Do they have a common ancestor? etc

Answer (score 2):

Declare it `public <T> Map<A, List<B<T>>> methodA() { ... }`, then the `T` is free for the caller to decided,

```
Map<A, List<B<String>> result = yourClass.methodA();
```

Comment: Which will either fail horribly if any `B` is not a `B<String>`, or limit what can be put inside the list.

Comment: @RobSpoor with this method declaration, implementing `methodA` in a way that fills that list with a differently typed `T` will not compile (not counting you using raw `B` and ignoring the warning) - the `List<B<T>>` in the parameter _is_ the "limit what can be put inside the list".

Comment: The issue here is that the implementation of `methodA` does not know what `T` is due to type erasure. That means that the method needs to use unchecked casts to `T` before it can add anything to the lists inside the map. There is only one value that's safe for this cast to `T`, and that's `null`.

Comment: @RobSpoor Type erasure is applied at runtime, the type of `T` is checked at compile time. There is no need for casts in the `methodA` implementation - it's just that it will need to retrieve the items from sources of which it knows will be applicable (eg a `Supplier<T>`).

Comment: At some point, the value for `T` will be needed if any of the lists need to be populated. There is only one place where `T` is specified, and that's in the method call. How can the implementation implement a `Supplier<T>` if it doesn't know what `T` is? There is a reason why methods often provide a `Class<T>` argument - so the implementation can determine what `T` is.