# How to tell sonar about a managed infinite loop

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a Java code as follows

```
try {
    while (true) {
        // do something without break but will throw an expected
        // exception in some random iteration of the loop
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handled properly
}
```

This is reported by Sonar to be a `Blocker Bug`, description as mentioned [here](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarjava/rules.html#RSPEC-2189). How can I get rid of this as I am actually expecting my loop to be ended by an exception and hence no break is required.

Comment: You can use the SuppressFBWarnings Annotation like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code. But looks like you should think over your solution

Comment: The rule does not support exceptions well, read this: [SONARJAVA-1944](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1944)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using exceptions for control flow is generally not considered good coding practice. Reasons for this can be found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why).

If you still want this to work, you may be able to do this:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        //code...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //code...
        break;            
    }
}
```

The `break` within the loop should make it work.

Comment: this is not working for me. I added an exception and an if, but it still gives that blocker.  And I need to figure this out this is a thread for a clean up process (cleans some data up in the DB) that needs to run for the full time the application is running.

Comment: @mpop If you have an 'if' that might be the reason that sonar is still complaining, without the full example it is difficult to tell why Sonar is complaining.