# How to exclude variable annotation in code coverage Junits Java

Tags: java, junit, aem, cobertura

I am facing one issue. My java bean has specific annotations to the bean.
For example:

```
@JcrProperty(name = "vermittlernummer")
private String vermittlernummer;
```

These annotations are included in code coverage when I run the build. So, it is impacting over all code coverage. I need to exclude the variable declaration annotations in Sonar cobertura code coverage.

How can we exclude variable annotation in code coverage.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd imagine that with "Java Bean" you mean Sling Models. In this case you might consider constructor based injection over field injection. That would make testing a lot easier and help you with your code coverage. See https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#basic-usage

Comment: Thanks for the response. it is not Sling model. It is simple java bean with annotations. We are using it for create,get and update node based on Json. I think there is way to exclude variable declaration in code coverage.

Comment: Did you see this related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code ?