# Why does it seem like Sonar is ignoring @SuppressWarnings

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube

In my Spring Boot application I have placed the annotation:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("PMD.EmptyMethodInAbstractClassShouldBeAbstract")
```

However it seems Sonar is ignoring it as I'm still getting:

```
Empty method com.mycompany.DefaultService.validateData(String, PrimaryView, int, ServiceHelper) could be declared abstract
```

I've also tried placing the `//NOPMD` comment on the line and for that I'm getting:

```
 Remove usage of this "NOPMD" suppression comment filter.      NEW      squid:S1310
```

I'm new to Spring Boot, and I don't even see any Sonar plugins being specified in any of my POM files... Is it possible that my project is using an old version of Sonar and that's why these annotations/comments have no effect?

To invoke Sonar I'm using th following command:

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar -DskipTests=true -Dsonar.language=java -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview -Dsonar.host.url=http://susday10058.corp.mycompany.com:9000
```

I've also tried invoking it with `-Dsonar.excludeMarker=NOPMD`
but that id not work either.

What am I missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code

Comment: SonarQube evolves fast. Which version of SonarQube do you use? What plugins and in which versions are installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use SonarQube identifiers.

Change:

```
@SuppressWarnings("PMD.EmptyMethodInAbstractClassShouldBeAbstract")
```

to:

```
@SuppressWarnings("pmd:EmptyMethodInAbstractClassShouldBeAbstract")
```

Identifiers are visible in the right upper corner:

[image: pmd:EmptyMethodInAbstractClassShouldBeAbstract description]

Comment: Thanks for yor response, but why does that not work for "pmd:GodClass"? i placed this just before the class eclaration... PMD seems to ignore it

Comment: ok, i see that to supress the God Class issue you need to @SuppressWarnings("PMD.GodClass") eventhough PMD displays "pmd:GodClass"