# Suppress Sonar's warning on import

Tags: java, sonarqube, suppress-warnings

**Disclaimer:** I am not asking about alternative imports. While this information may be useful, feel free to leave a comment; but any answer containing something like *use another import* will be downvoted. **I am asking about how to suppress the warning**. Thanks!

Here is the import I use:

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties;
```

Sonar complains about it saying:

> Use classes from the Java API instead of Sun classes. (squid:S1191)

How can I suppress this warning?

Comment: Add a comment `// NOSONAR` to the line.

Comment: Can you please try import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties; // NOSONAR .

Comment: In eclipse you can deactivate the rule

Comment: thanks, guys, `// NOSONAR` seems to be working. This should be an answer!

Comment: @user7294900 yes and no. The import section is quite tricky where you can't use the SupressWarning. So it is natural to raise a particular question about import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try:

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXWSProperties; // NOSONAR
```

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, this is related to [turn sonar off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code)

But adding `@SupressWarning` isn't possible in import statements, so your options:

- Add at the end of the line `//NOSONAR` - for specific line
- Deactivate rule squid:S1191 (available in Eclipse) - if you have multiple lines

Comment: Do you know of a way to use //NOSONAR for a block of code?

Comment: @pytry you can add `@SuppressWarnings` on method

Comment: I should have been more specific. I don't want to add this to a method; I want to add it to ignore warnings on imports and package declarations, where you can't use annotations.

Fun little tidbit; there seems to be a rule that shows a warning when you suppress all warnings using "//NOSONAR" .... so yeah. That's annoying.