# Ignore warning on deprecated code usage from third party library or particular package

Tags: java, sonarqube, deprecated, static-analysis

My project uses third party library (let's call it X) with a lot of deprecated code. Sonarqube reports a lot of issues every time I call depracated method or use deprecated type from library X. I found that rule `squid:CallToDeprecatedMethod` is responsible for that.

What I want to achieve is to have rule `squid:CallToDeprecatedMethod` enabled for all types and method references excluding library X (or particular package from library X). What's more I want to do it externally without any sonar specific exclusion marks in the codebase (i.e. `@SuppressWarnings("squid:xxx")`)

I tried Sonarqube's administration->analysis scope options but didn't find anything. Also checked StackOverflow, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code) but found nothing.

My SonarQube version is 5.6.6.

Answer (score -1):

While sonar analysis you can pass sonar exclusion if you dont want in code.

mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.exclusion= **/pattern/*.java

Comment: I don't want to ignore my source files. All files need to be checked. I want rule squid:CallToDeprecatedMethod to ignore deprecated code from third party's library.