# How to fix the Sonar critical issue on Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube

I'm getting a critical sonar issue "*Using regular expressions is security-sensitive*" when using the code

```
Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
```

Can anyone help to fix this? Is there any alternatives available for this?

Comment: If you need more help, please update the question with the exact regex you are using.

Comment: Pattern newpattern = Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
 
 value = newpattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");   this is the code

Comment: Please add it to the question

Comment: Try `"src=([^']+)"` pattern or `"src = ([^']+)"`.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this Sonarsource documenation](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4784),

> This rule flags any execution of a hardcoded regular expression which has at least 3 characters and at least two instances of any of the following characters: `*+{.`.

So, you must make sure your pattern complies with the rule.

Alternatively, you may disable the warnings by [Turning Sonar off for certain code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code).

Comment: So if our pattern doesn't comply with the rule, what exactly should we need to do then?
My regular expression is ".*\\d+.*" and how should I comply with the rule flag.

Comment: @ShrutikaNinawe Ignore the warning, or use simpler regexps with just one quantifier, `"src='([^']*)'"` or `"src = '([^']*)'"`.

Comment: @ShrutikaNinawe You may simply use `[0-9]` to check if a string contains a digit or disable the warning.