# Regex to find string with __ and multiple _ and then __ to get desired output

Tags: java, regex, scala

I'm trying to create a regex to find a string with a double-underscore `__`, multiple underscores `_` and then another double-underscore `__` and extract the part before the final `__<string>`
The first delimiter should be `__` and then multiple `_`, and string ends with `__<String>`

The result should be such that string before the second __

example 1- `UK__SATHISH_KUMAR__LONDON` should result to `UK__SATHISH_KUMAR`

example 2- `UK__SATHISH_KUMAR_MALE__LONDON` should result to `UK__SATHISH_KUMAR_MALE`

```
public static final String RULE_FILE_NAME_PATTERN =
    "(([a-zA-Z]+)__(([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)))(__[\\w]+)*";
```

This pattern works but fails sonarqube as it's long, can some one help to get a shorter regex?

Comment: [Turn this warning off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code),  sonarqube is doing a bad job here.

Comment: Hmmm, it appears requirement has been changed -- OP originally specified extracting substring `before the second __` thus presuming there could be additional `__`, but the latest edit revised it to extracting `before the final __<string>` which would be a much simpler match (e.g. using a `.*` greedy match).

Comment: @Stephen P how to approve the suggestedEdits

Answer (score 0):

You can group the `[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+` sub-pattern into a non-capturing group of repetitive occurrences as `(?:[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+)*`, and optionalize certain parts of the pattern in accordance with your specific requirement, as shown below:

```
val p = """([A-Za-z]+__(?:[A-Za-z]+(?:_[A-Za-z]+)?)*)(?:__.*)?""".r

val strings = List(
  "uk__john_doe__london__edmonton",
  "us__zoe_smith_female__new_york__manhattan",
  "au__dave_clark_male__sidney",
  "fr__alex__paris",
  "jp__yumiko",
  "no_double_underscore"
)

strings.collect{ case p(x) => x }
// res1: List[String] = List(
//   "uk__john_doe",
//   "us__zoe_smith_female",
//   "au__dave_clark_male",
//   "fr__alex",
//   "jp__yumiko"
// )
```

---

Note that the Regex pattern can be simplified using lazy matches like below if the string doesn't have to strictly follow the `alphabets_alphabets` sub-pattern:

```
val p = """(.*?__.*?)(?:__.*)?""".r
```

Comment: Thanks @Leo C  ..The pattern works for all logics and string .except the last pattern of string..


1) fr__alex__paris  to fr__alex
and doesnt work for 
2) fr__alex to fr__alex

Comment: ***To be precise , these are the output i expects***
 ====================================================================
* 1) "STRING1__STRING2" = "STRING1__STRING2"  *
* 2) "STRING1__STRING2__STRING3_STRING4_STRING5" = "STRING1__STRING2"  *
 *3) "STRING1__STRING2_STRING3__STRING4_STRING5" = "STRING1__STRING2_STRING3"  *
* 4) "STRING1__STRING2_STRING3_STRING4" = "STRING1__STRING2_STRING3_STRING4"  *
* 5) "STRING1__STRING2_STRING3_STRING4__STRING5" = "STRING1__STRING2_STRING3_STRING4" *

Comment: Based on your example, you can simply make the last substring with leading `__` optional.  Please see my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

2. sorry the UK was just an example it can be any characters ENGLAND__SATHISH_KUMAR__LONDON

Still not clear

Assuming it can can any word character,at least one, you can use

```
(\w+__.*)__
```

1. 

Your question needs precision because you return characters UK before what you declare as first delimiter __

Assuming you want always 2 characters before you can do

```
(\w{2}__.*)__
```

Comment: sorry the UK was just an example it can be any characters ENGLAND__SATHISH_KUMAR__LONDON

Comment: See my updated answer but you always have to define what you want :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need all the text before the final __ you can just use:

```
(.*)__
```

Its a greedy match and will capture everything in group 1.