# SonarLint: Suppress specific line warning in Android Studio

Tags: android, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

There is a special case in our code where we need to call `setText` with `getText` of the same TextView. SonarLint warn this with `kotlin:S1656`, to suppress it we use `@SuppressWarnings` annotation but it does not work. It started showing an error to the IDE and the warning from SonarLint still there. `//NOSONAR` is not working as well

[image]

[image]

No action is available as well for suppressing it.
[image]

Comment: Can you link to the documentation that `kotlin:S1656` is the correct suppression to be using?

Comment: Also have you done "more actions" to see what suppression the IDE recommends?

Comment: @Blundell I added more context to the question, TLDR; no action for suppression is being shown and the rule seems to be correct as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you put the `SuppressWarnings` annotation before your method?

```kotlin
// Sonarlint plugin version 6.8.0.50884

@SuppressWarnings("kotlin:S1656")
fun yourMethod() {
    // ...
  withContext(coroutineDispatcherMain) {
        // Set the text again to fix images overlapping text
        htmlTextView.text = htmlTextView.text
  }

}
```

I also wonder that if `htmlTextView.invalidate()` would work for you.

UPDATE:

`SuppressWarnings` annotation is also available for `LOCAL_VARIABLE` but I think the problem is more complicated in kotlin code.

If you examine the byte code of these lines below, you can see that some.num = ... is some.setNum(...) in byte code.

Sonar plugin's code analyser may not handle this kind of kotlin specific codes.

```kotlin
class Sonar {

  private val some = Something(0)
  private var member = 0

  @Deprecated("...")
  fun myNumber(): Int = 1

  fun doThat() {
    // local variable working
    @SuppressWarnings("kotlin:S1874") // Code annotated as deprecated should not be used
    val localNum = myNumber()

    // not working
    @SuppressWarnings("kotlin:S1874")
    some.num = myNumber()

    // not working
    @SuppressWarnings("kotlin:S1874")
    member = myNumber()

    // ...
  }

}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! By the way can we only suppress it by putting the annotation in the method or class and not by line?

Comment: One more question, how do you write it with multiple rules? I tried `@SuppressWarnings({"kotlin:S6310","kotlin:S1656"})` but it is mark as an error.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("kotlin:S6310", "kotlin:S1656")`

Answer (score 0):

I found the docs for the issue to confirm its the right number: https://rules.sonarsource.com/kotlin/RSPEC-1656

Also read the source at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-intellij but not much help.

It seems like "`// NOSONAR`" is what you want (I know you said you tried it, but did you have the space? And have it at the end of the line?)

```
htmlTextView.text = htmlTextView.text // NOSONAR
```

Just a guess here, but you could also try:

```
@SuppressWarnings("RSPEC:S1656")
```

lastly to check suppress is working you can ignore everything:

```
@SuppressWarnings("all")
htmlTextView.text = htmlTextView.text
```

Big discussion here: [Turning Sonar off for certain code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code)

This article also gives you options to choose from: https://docs.codescan.io/hc/en-us/articles/360012109711-Ignoring-violations

Comment: None of the above work tho I did not try the last one since I just want to suppress that specific rule just for this line.

Comment: You should try the last one to help you understand the problem more. You could also check your sonar config to see if suppression is enabled. Also check the import you are using for suppresswarnings to check its the correct annotation.