# "partial" is gratuitous in this context using SonarQube 5.2

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We using SonarQube 5.2, the Rule

> Redundant modifiers should be removed

does not working correctly.

The class is defined in multiple files, therefore it be has declared as **partial**, but SonarQube mark this as bug.

**Has anyone an idea to fix this?**

Comment: What language is the code in?

Comment: C# .net framework 4.5

Comment: Please provide some code on how to reproduce this false positive

Comment: *public partial class DerivativesOperatorModel* this class is declared en many files e.g: ClearingPartnerAsignaConciliationModel.cs, ClearingPartnerDifferentialCommissionsMaintenanceModel.cs, learingPartnerExcerciceOptionsMaintenanceModel.cs,ClearingPartnerOptionsExerciseModel.cs, etc. I´m  just  analazyng this code, I do not wrote this code.

Comment: Omar, please edit question instead of adding comments (example: add code to question)

Comment: If you are using the *sonar-runner* directly then it might be because the analysis is performed post-build one file at a time. See [this blog[(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2016/01/04/sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild-v1-1-released-static-analysis-now-executed-during-the-build-x.aspx) for more information on the issue and how it is fixed in builds using the *SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild* v1.1 with C# plugin v4.4.
As as test, add a second empty *public partial class DerivativesOperatorModel* declaration in a file containing a "real" declaration and see if the issue disappears.

Comment: That´s right, I'm using MSBuild 14.0, I updated SonarRunner from 1.0.1 to 1.1, and also updated C# plugin from 4.3 to 4.4. Now the analisys did not show false positive. Thank you duncanpMS

Answer (score 0):

try putting //NOSONAR

For example : public partial class MyClass **//NOSONAR**

Similar thing to skip the rule is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708628/in-sonar-how-to-prevent-checking-some-rules-in-some-packages) too

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to skip the rule, I think that _sonarqube_ is not working fine